# Graalvm unknown identifier when passing java object to js

Tags: java, graalvm, polyglot, graaljs

I am trying to run this Graalvm sample code:

```java
package org.homi.scripting.experimental;
import org.graalvm.polyglot.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.*;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class ScriptEngine {
    
    public static class Name {
        @HostAccess.Export public String name = "hello";

        @HostAccess.Export
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Name n = new Name();
        Context context = Context.newBuilder("js")
                .allowAllAccess(true)
                .allowIO(true)
                .allowPolyglotAccess(PolyglotAccess.ALL)
                .build();
        context.getPolyglotBindings().putMember("name", n);
        context.eval("js", "var name = Polyglot.import('name');");
        context.eval("js", "console.log(name.getName())");
        
        
    }
}
```

I am getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" TypeError: invokeMember (getName) on org.homi.scripting.experimental.Name@2313052e failed due to: Unknown identifier: getName
    at <js> :program(Unnamed:1:12-25)
    at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:379)
    at ScriptEngine/org.homi.scripting.experimental.ScriptEngine.tester(ScriptEngine.java:43)
    at ScriptEngine/org.homi.scripting.experimental.ScriptEngine.main(ScriptEngine.java:29)
```

I'm new to graalvm, what am I doing wrong? I was following this demo from the documentation (see the section on host interoperability):
https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code and the stack trace don't match, for example the code lacks the `tester` method

```
    at ScriptEngine/org.homi.scripting.experimental.ScriptEngine.tester(ScriptEngine.java:43)
```

When you specify `allowAllAccess(true)` you allow all access, so the HostAccess stops being necesary.

The code in the question works for me and prints hello as expected.

Comment: Apologies, had a typo in my post and forgot to edit the stack trace. The issue ended up being not exporting my module in my module-info.java! Took me a while to find.

Comment: Glad it got resolved! what's interesting the modules aren't anywhere in the code/stacktrace. I wouldn't think about it, thanks for clarifying, will try to remember for the future!